# Using ActiveSupport::Inflector with a class conflict

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Setting an inflection for `SendGrid` means we can make an exception to Rails' filenaming schemes. We can name models `SendGrid...` and not have to name files `send_grid_...`. However, it's introduced an issue here relating to a dependency. I'm using the `sendgrid-actionmailer` gem, which registers an ingress using the module name `ActionMailbox::Ingresses::Sendgrid`, but the previous acronym definition means the lookup expects `SendGrid`.

`config/initializers/inflections.rb`:

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections(:en) do |inflect|
  ...
  inflect.acronym 'SendGrid'
end
```

When running in production, where I use sendgrid-actionmailer:

```
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/actionmailbox-6.0.3.2/app/controllers/action_mailbox/ingresses/sendgrid/inbound_emails_controller.rb:47:in `<module:ActionMailbox>': uninitialized constant ActionMailbox::Ingresses::Sendgrid (NameError)
Did you mean?  ActionMailbox::Ingresses::SendGrid
SendGrid
```

[A maintainer suggests this problem relates more to ActiveSupport than sendgrid-actionmailer](https://github.com/eddiezane/sendgrid-actionmailer/issues/89#issuecomment-680930479), and I agree. He's suggested that an interim fix for this would be to remove the acronym declaration and use Sendgrid instead. Is there a more permanent solution that allows us to leave the acronym declaration in?

Comment: What defines `ActionMailbox::Ingresses::Sendgrid` ?

Comment: The `actionmailbox` module of Rails - code is [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/tree/master/actionmailbox).

Answer (score 1):

Defining inflections on `ActiveSupport::Inflections` affects how they're loaded globally. Thanks to the [Rails docs](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/autoloading_and_reloading_constants.html#customizing-inflections), I figured out that you can override inflections on Rails' loader. I ended up needing to add the following to an initializer (`.rb` file under `config/initializers`):

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

Rails.autoloaders.each do |autoloader|
  autoloader.inflector.inflect(
    'sendgrid' => 'Sendgrid'
  )
end
```

This restores the default as far as the loader is aware.